# How to upload images to the server using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I have to upload an image to server using Retrofit2.

Everything has worked fine at first, but after I re-check it before the release the API failed that can't upload the image but still works using postman!

My code is :

```
MultipartBody.Part imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image",
            image.getFilename(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.get(image.getMimeType()), image.getFile()));

RequestBody sessionPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, sessionToken);
RequestBody userIdPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, userId);
RequestBody pictureTypePart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, pictureType.pictureTypeValue());

return dubaingNetwork.uploadProfilePic(accessToken,userIdPart,sessionPart,imagePart,pictureTypePart);
```

My api interface is:

```
@Multipart
@POST(Urls.UPLOAD_PROFILE_PIC)
Observable<UploadProfilePicResponse> uploadProfilePic(@Header(ACCESS_TOKEN_FIELD_NAME) String accessToken,
                                                      @Part(USER_ID_FIELD_NAME) RequestBody userId,
                                                      @Part(SESSION_TOKEN_FIELD_NAME) RequestBody sessionToken,
                                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                                      @Part("image_type") RequestBody pictureType);
```

**Edit:** I tried to convert it to urlencoded type with the image converted to string Base64 and the parameters as a field but still the same error on phone and in postman still works, so I don't think it's a server-side error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error code 400 and the file upload status which is boolean returns null

Comment: I update my question

Comment: @AliHabbash Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android?noredirect=1#comment111031344_62783444